# In 2PC what happens in case of failure to commit?

Tags: distributed-computing, consensus

In 2PC what happens if coordinator asks 3 participants to commit and the second one fails with no response to the coordinator.

A client arrives asks the second node for the value, the second node has just come up but did not manage to commit so it returns an old value... Is that a fault of 2PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The missing part of 2PC - 2PR(2 Phases Read)**

If any of the commit messages lost or doesn't take effect for some reason at some participants, the resource remains at prepared state(which is **uncertain**), even after a restart, because prepared state must be persisted in non-volatile storage before the coordinator can ever send a commit message.

Any one tries to read any **uncertain** resource, must refer to the coordinator to determine the exact state of that resource. Once determined, you can choose the right version of value.

For your case, the second node returns the new value(with the help of coordinator to find out new value is really committed, and old value is stale).

---------- edit --------------

Some implementations use Exclusive Lock during prepare phase, which means, once prepared, no other can **read** or write the prepared resource. So, before participant committed, any one tries to read, must **wait**.

Answer (score 1):

If the coordinator is asking them to commit, then it means that all participants have already answered that they are *prepared* to commit. Prepared means that the participant is *guaranteed* to be able to commit. There is no failure. If the node vanished in a meteor strike, then the node is restored from the HA/DR data and the restored mode resumes the transaction and proceeds with the commit.

Participants in 2PC are durable, persisted coordinators capable of backup and restore. In theory in the case when one of the participants cannot be restored, then every participant, and the coordinators, are all restored back in time before the last coordinated transaction. In practice, all coordinators support enforcing cases when a participant is lost and the transaction will be manually forced into one state or another, see [Resolve Transactions Manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754134%28v%3dws.10%29) or [Resolving indoubt transactions manually](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.2pc.doc/doc/t0004636.html).

Comment: But still node received final commit command and then vanished, coordinator was doing on the meanwhile another state change which has committed while node is down, node comes up, replays the commit and serves and old value?

Comment: Once committed, a transaction is committed. There is no 'old value' or 'new value' or 'change state after commit'.